# Parsing tables from .txt (text) files

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, text-parsing, memory-profiling

I have some profiling results from a python profiler, shown below:

```
Filename: main.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    30    121.8 MiB    121.8 MiB   @profile(stream=f)
    31                             def parse_data(data):
    32    121.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       Y=data["price"].values
    33    121.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       Y=np.log(Y)
    34    121.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       features=data.columns
    35    121.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       X1=list(set(features)-set(["price"]))
    36    126.3 MiB      4.5 MiB       X=data[X1].values
    37    126.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       ss=StandardScaler()
    38    124.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       X=ss.fit_transform(X)
    39    124.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       return X,Y


Filename: main.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    41    127.1 MiB    127.1 MiB   @profile(stream=f)
    42                             def linearRegressionfit(Xt,Yt,Xts,Yts):
    43    127.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       lr=LinearRegression()
    44    131.2 MiB      4.1 MiB       model=lr.fit(Xt,Yt)
    45    132.0 MiB      0.8 MiB       predict=lr.predict(Xts)
    46
```

Now, I need to obtain these results for plotting and other purpose. But the text is not something very handy. The table shows line-by-line profiling results. How can I get a pandas dataframe or a tabular version **which can be used to obtain any row or column from this table** ?

P.S. I have visited `regex` and `parsimonious` but can't seem to get them to use in my case.

Comment: Can you show an example of the desired output? Which lines do you want to skip? What to do with missing values, like Mem usage/Increment in lines 32 and 42?

Comment: I aim to get different dataframes per function. The different functions are distinguished by the `@profile` decorator. The tables would be great if in the same order as in this text file. This would allow me to simply iterate over all lines and get the increment in memory usage (total + per function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a bit of parsing exercise. With standard split() and some minor adjustments, you can get a pretty clean data frame in a few lines of code.

```
txt = '''
Filename: main.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    30    121.8 MiB    121.8 MiB   @profile(stream=f)
    31                             def parse_data(data):
    32    121.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       Y=data["price"].values
    33    121.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       Y=np.log(Y)
    34    121.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       features=data.columns
    35    121.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       X1=list(set(features)-set(["price"]))
    36    126.3 MiB      4.5 MiB       X=data[X1].values
    37    126.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       ss=StandardScaler()
    38    124.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       X=ss.fit_transform(X)
    39    124.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       return X,Y


Filename: main.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    41    127.1 MiB    127.1 MiB   @profile(stream=f)
    42                             def linearRegressionfit(Xt,Yt,Xts,Yts):
    43    127.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       lr=LinearRegression()
    44    131.2 MiB      4.1 MiB       model=lr.fit(Xt,Yt)
    45    132.0 MiB      0.8 MiB       predict=lr.predict(Xts)
'''

import pandas as pd

lines = []
for line in txt.split('\n'):
    #print(line)
    if line.startswith('Filename'): continue
    if line.startswith('Line'): continue
    if line.startswith('='): continue
    if line == '': continue
    data = [i.strip() for i in line.split()]
    #Fix def lines
    if data[1] == 'def':
        data = [data[0],'','','','',' '.join(data[1:4])]

    data = [data[0], ' '.join(data[1:3]), ' '.join(data[3:5]), data[-1]]
    lines.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=['Line #', 'Mem usage', 'Increment','Line Contents'])

print(df)

   Line #  Mem usage  Increment                            Line Contents
0      30  121.8 MiB  121.8 MiB                       @profile(stream=f)
1      31                                          def parse_data(data):
2      32  121.8 MiB    0.0 MiB                   Y=data["price"].values
3      33  121.8 MiB    0.0 MiB                              Y=np.log(Y)
4      34  121.8 MiB    0.0 MiB                    features=data.columns
5      35  121.8 MiB    0.0 MiB    X1=list(set(features)-set(["price"]))
6      36  126.3 MiB    4.5 MiB                        X=data[X1].values
7      37  126.3 MiB    0.0 MiB                      ss=StandardScaler()
8      38  124.6 MiB    0.0 MiB                    X=ss.fit_transform(X)
9      39  124.6 MiB    0.0 MiB                                      X,Y
10     41  127.1 MiB  127.1 MiB                       @profile(stream=f)
11     42                        def linearRegressionfit(Xt,Yt,Xts,Yts):
12     43  127.1 MiB    0.0 MiB                    lr=LinearRegression()
13     44  131.2 MiB    4.1 MiB                      model=lr.fit(Xt,Yt)
14     45  132.0 MiB    0.8 MiB                  predict=lr.predict(Xts)
```

You can then split the data frame when `'@profile'` is in `'Line Contents'`.

For example:

```
split_idx = df[df['Line Contents'].str.startswith('@profile')].index
dataframes = []
for i, idx in enumerate(split_idx):
    try:
        dataframes.append(df.iloc[idx, split_idx[i+1]])
    except IndexError:
        dataframes.append(df.iloc[idx:])


print(dataframes[0])
print('======')
print(dataframes[1])

   Line #  Mem usage  Increment                            Line Contents
0      30  121.8 MiB  121.8 MiB                       @profile(stream=f)
1      31                                          def parse_data(data):
2      32  121.8 MiB    0.0 MiB                   Y=data["price"].values
3      33  121.8 MiB    0.0 MiB                              Y=np.log(Y)
4      34  121.8 MiB    0.0 MiB                    features=data.columns
5      35  121.8 MiB    0.0 MiB    X1=list(set(features)-set(["price"]))
6      36  126.3 MiB    4.5 MiB                        X=data[X1].values
7      37  126.3 MiB    0.0 MiB                      ss=StandardScaler()
8      38  124.6 MiB    0.0 MiB                    X=ss.fit_transform(X)
9      39  124.6 MiB    0.0 MiB                                      X,Y
10     41  127.1 MiB  127.1 MiB                       @profile(stream=f)
11     42                        def linearRegressionfit(Xt,Yt,Xts,Yts):
12     43  127.1 MiB    0.0 MiB                    lr=LinearRegression()
13     44  131.2 MiB    4.1 MiB                      model=lr.fit(Xt,Yt)
14     45  132.0 MiB    0.8 MiB                  predict=lr.predict(Xts)
======
   Line #  Mem usage  Increment                            Line Contents
10     41  127.1 MiB  127.1 MiB                       @profile(stream=f)
11     42                        def linearRegressionfit(Xt,Yt,Xts,Yts):
12     43  127.1 MiB    0.0 MiB                    lr=LinearRegression()
13     44  131.2 MiB    4.1 MiB                      model=lr.fit(Xt,Yt)
14     45  132.0 MiB    0.8 MiB                  predict=lr.predict(Xts)
```

Comment: This is perfect ! Thank You very much :)
I made some corrections to the code to include some other naive cases. I think I was going for an overkill with regex

Comment: @PeDro Your edits were changing the code too much. I have rejected them. Use the code I wrote as an example, modify your own implementation as you think it is best.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear if you want to parse the entire text or if you have a text file for each table and want to parse the table.

If you want to create a pandas dataframe from each table, using the `skiprows` parameter to `read_fwf` should work (this skips the non-standard line in the file but parses the rest). Here I have stored the contents of the first table into a file `sample-1.txt` and read it using `read_fwf`.

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.read_fwf('sample-1.txt', skiprows=[1])
```

This gives the following data frame.

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Line #           10 non-null int64
Mem usage        9 non-null object
Increment        9 non-null object
Line Contents    10 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 392.0+ bytes
```

If you want to split it into separate tables, you would have to break the file at each mention of `Filename: main.py`.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution.

It is possible to produce time series data out of text using [TTP](https://github.com/dmulyalin/ttp).

Sample code:

```
from ttp import ttp
import pprint

data_1 = """
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    30    121.8 MiB    121.8 MiB   @profile(stream=f)
    31                             def parse_data(data):
    32    121.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       Y=data["price"].values
    33    121.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       Y=np.log(Y)
    34    121.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       features=data.columns
    35    121.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       X1=list(set(features)-set(["price"]))
    36    126.3 MiB      4.5 MiB       X=data[X1].values
    37    126.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       ss=StandardScaler()
    38    124.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       X=ss.fit_transform(X)
    39    124.6 MiB      0.0 MiB       return X,Y
"""

data_2 = """
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    41    127.1 MiB    127.1 MiB   @profile(stream=f)
    42                             def linearRegressionfit(Xt,Yt,Xts,Yts):
    43    127.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       lr=LinearRegression()
    44    131.2 MiB      4.1 MiB       model=lr.fit(Xt,Yt)
    45    132.0 MiB      0.8 MiB       predict=lr.predict(Xts)
    46    
"""

template = """
<vars>
timestamp = "get_timestamp_iso"
</vars>

<group macro="process">
Line_N    Mem_usage    Increment   Line_Contents {{ _headers_ }}
{{ @timestamp | set(timestamp) }}
</group>

<macro>
def process(data):
    # remove ===== matches
    if "====" in data["Line_N"]:
        return False
        
    # convert Increment to integer    
    incr = data.pop("Increment").split(" ")[0]
    data["Increment_MiB"] = float(incr) if incr else 0.0
    
    # convert Mem usage to integer 
    memuse = data.pop("Mem_usage").split(" ")[0]
    data["Mem_usage_MiB"] = float(memuse) if memuse else 0.0
    
    return data
</macro>
"""

parser = ttp(template=template)
parser.add_input(data_1)
parser.add_input(data_2)
parser.parse()
res = parser.result(structure="flat_list")
pprint.pprint(res)

# will print:
# [{'@timestamp': '2020-08-01T21:57:51.734448+00:00',
#   'Increment_MiB': 121.8,
#   'Line_Contents': '@profile(stream=f)',
#   'Line_N': '30',
#   'Mem_usage_MiB': 121.8},
#  {'@timestamp': '2020-08-01T21:57:51.734448+00:00',
#   'Increment_MiB': 0.0,
#   'Line_Contents': 'def parse_data(data):',
#   'Line_N': '31',
#   'Mem_usage_MiB': 0.0},
#  {'@timestamp': '2020-08-01T21:57:51.734448+00:00',
#   'Increment_MiB': 0.0,
#   'Line_Contents': 'Y=data["price"].values',
#   'Line_N': '32',
#   'Mem_usage_MiB': 121.8},
#  {'@timestamp': '2020-08-01T21:57:51.734448+00:00',
#   'Increment_MiB': 0.0,
#   'Line_Contents': 'Y=np.log(Y)',
#   'Line_N': '33',
#   'Mem_usage_MiB': 121.8},
#  {'@timestamp': '2020-08-01T21:57:51.734448+00:00',
#   'Increment_MiB': 0.0,
#   'Line_Contents': 'features=data.columns',
#   'Line_N': '34',
#   'Mem_usage_MiB': 121.8},
#  {'@timestamp': '2020-08-01T21:57:51.734448+00:00',
#   'Increment_MiB': 0.0,
#   'Line_Contents': 'X1=list(set(features)-set(["price"]))',
#   'Line_N': '35',
#   'Mem_usage_MiB': 121.8},
#  {'@timestamp': '2020-08-01T21:57:51.734448+00:00',
#   'Increment_MiB': 4.5,
#   'Line_Contents': 'X=data[X1].values',
#   'Line_N': '36',
#   'Mem_usage_MiB': 126.3},
#  {'@timestamp': '2020-08-01T21:57:51.734448+00:00',
#   'Increment_MiB': 0.0,
#   'Line_Contents': 'ss=StandardScaler()',
#   'Line_N': '37',
#   'Mem_usage_MiB': 126.3},
#  {'@timestamp': '2020-08-01T21:57:51.734448+00:00',
#   'Increment_MiB': 0.0,
#   'Line_Contents': 'X=ss.fit_transform(X)',
#   'Line_N': '38',
#   'Mem_usage_MiB': 124.6},
#  {'@timestamp': '2020-08-01T21:57:51.734448+00:00',
#   'Increment_MiB': 0.0,
#   'Line_Contents': 'return X,Y',
#   'Line_N': '39',
#   'Mem_usage_MiB': 124.6},
#  {'@timestamp': '2020-08-01T21:57:51.738444+00:00',
#   'Increment_MiB': 127.1,
#   'Line_Contents': '@profile(stream=f)',
#   'Line_N': '41',
#   'Mem_usage_MiB': 127.1},
#  {'@timestamp': '2020-08-01T21:57:51.738444+00:00',
#   'Increment_MiB': 0.0,
#   'Line_Contents': 'def linearRegressionfit(Xt,Yt,Xts,Yts):',
#   'Line_N': '42',
#   'Mem_usage_MiB': 0.0},
#  {'@timestamp': '2020-08-01T21:57:51.738444+00:00',
#   'Increment_MiB': 0.0,
#   'Line_Contents': 'lr=LinearRegression()',
#   'Line_N': '43',
#   'Mem_usage_MiB': 127.1},
#  {'@timestamp': '2020-08-01T21:57:51.738444+00:00',
#   'Increment_MiB': 4.1,
#   'Line_Contents': 'model=lr.fit(Xt,Yt)',
#   'Line_N': '44',
#   'Mem_usage_MiB': 131.2},
#  {'@timestamp': '2020-08-01T21:57:51.738444+00:00',
#   'Increment_MiB': 0.8,
#   'Line_Contents': 'predict=lr.predict(Xts)',
#   'Line_N': '45',
#   'Mem_usage_MiB': 132.0}]
```

If you push above data to Elasticsearch for indexing, it can be visualised using Grafana fairly easy, you can construct queries to display counters on a per line basis referencing Line_N or Line_Contents variable.

But for above template to work, TTP need to be installed from github repo - 0.3.0 release available on PyPI does not have required features. New release coming soon though.